# How to expolde value from input type checkbox for auto sum in this code?

Tags: javascript, php

How to explode value from input type checkbox for auto sum in this code ?

....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="checkbox" value="bgh_9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="ujh_19.99" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="hhb_27.50" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="uu_45.65" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="jjhh_87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="hhh_87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>    
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clickHandlers = (function () {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1"),
        totalcost = document.getElementById("totalcost"),
// if this is always the last input in the form, we could avoid hitting document again with
// totalcost  = form1[form1.length - 1];
        sum = 0;
    form1.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var thisInput = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (thisInput.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
            if (thisInput.checked) {
                sum  += parseFloat(thisInput.value);
            }  else {
                if (thisInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {
                    sum -= parseFloat(thisInput.value);
                }
            }
            totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "";
        }
    }
    return null;
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Go through **[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eymSZ/)**, so you will get idea how to do that.

Comment: A.P. ---- this demo `value="50"` but in my code `value="abc_50"`

i must to explode forst.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the checkbox value.

```
var val = thisInput.value, // "bgh_9.99"
    split_array = val.split("_"), // ["bgh", "9.99"]
    number = split_array[1]; // "9.99"
sum += parseFloat(number); // 9.99
```

Comment: Sure, it can be simplified to `parseFloat(thisInput.value.split("_")[1])`